# How do I automatically disable cellular data when at home?

Tags: wi-fi, mobile-data

I do not get service at my house.

The only way I can use my phone is over wifi.

If cell service is turned on, but has no bars, I don't receive text messages properly, they take forever if they come at all. When i turn off the cell data, I get the text messages.

How do I automatically turn off the cell data when im at home, and turn it on when i leave the house?

Comment: What phone are you using?  Some phones have this built-in.  Or you can download apps to do it.

Comment: i have a TCL 20s. can it be done without rooting?

Answer (score 1):

I am using an app called **MyProfiles**, but I can't find it on Play Store.

However,  [**aProfiles**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.aprofile) will do the job for you.  It is also under development currently, others appear to have stagnated.

- You can set up profiles (with what's on or off, sound levels, etc)
- Then set up rules to switch profiles automatically (when Bluetooth/wifi turn on or off)
- It also supports location-based profiles.

[image: Screenshots]

I am not associated with it in any way.

Comment: FYI, the "switching mobile data" action requires root access.